# Custom mega menu issues

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal, megamenu

I have included a mega menu on my website made up using Bootstrap, Javascript, PHP and CSS.

currently, there are tabs at the bottom which change the list that I am viewing in the menu... Men, Women, Kids and sport.

In order to change from one tab to the next I am required to click the links.

I would like to change it from click to hover/mouseover and also move off the bottom so it is at the side sort of like in its own column.

I also have a problem where currently when I hover over the dropdown, the background of the dropdown tab changes color from blue to brown. when I leave the dropdown the background changes back to blue. However, if I open the mega menu drop down and then click one of the sub tabs in the menu to change the products displayed the dropdown background stays constantly browm as if the menu is constantly active, even if I hover over a different dropdown on the main navbar.

If anyone can help with any of these issues, that would be great.

I have included the code as below. (so far an exact copy of what is on above link)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://www.sneakermission.com/uploads/3/1/2/7/31279819/5617441.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 50px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a,
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.nav-list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav-list>li {
  padding: 20px 15px 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav-list>li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}

.nav-list>li>a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list>li>a>span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  padding: 20px 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-megadropdown-tabs">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown active">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="men">
                      <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Running.png"><span>Running</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Basketball.png"><span>Basketball</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Football.png"><span>Football</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Soccer.png"><span>Soccer</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_MensTraining.png"><span>Men's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_WomensTraining.png"><span>Women's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="women">
                      <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Running.png"><span>Running</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Basketball.png"><span>Basketball</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Football.png"><span>Football</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Soccer.png"><span>Soccer</span></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="kids">
                      <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Running.png"><span>Running</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Basketball.png"><span>Basketball</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Football.png"><span>Football</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Soccer.png"><span>Soccer</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_MensTraining.png"><span>Men's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_WomensTraining.png"><span>Women's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="sports">
                      <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Basketball.png"><span>Basketball</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Football.png"><span>Football</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_Soccer.png"><span>Soccer</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_MensTraining.png"><span>Men's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="#"><img src="http://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/globalAssets/menu_header_images/OneNike_Global_Nav_Icons_WomensTraining.png"><span>Women's Training</span></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#men" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Men</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#women" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Women</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#kids" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kids</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sports" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sports</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code snippet and got two errors:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 221,
  "colno": 1
}
{
  "message": "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery",
  "filename": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "lineno": 6,
  "colno": 31
}
```

You need to include your library JavaScript and your library CSS at the top of your HTML (I have edited the question to reflect this):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
```

> In order to change from one tab to the next I am required to click the links.
>   I would like to change it from click to hover/mouseover

The default behaviour of a link is to be clickable. If you want the event to be a mouseover instead of a click, change them to a `<li>` (remove the `<a>`) and add a hover event.

From a usability point of view, I would leave them as a click event. When I move my mouse over something, I want a preview of what it does (e.g. the hover event should be to display a tooltip or see the URL of the link target in the bottom left of the browser), I don't want it to actually do the thing until I click on it.

> and also move off the bottom so it is at the side sort of like in its own column.

It is hard to visualise what you mean by that, because your full styling is not visible in the snippet.

> I also have a problem where currently when I hover over the dropdown,
>   the background of the dropdown tab changes color from blue to brown.
>   when I leave the dropdown the background changes back to blue.
>   However, if I open the mega menu drop down and then click one of the
>   sub tabs in the menu to change the products displayed the dropdown
>   background stays constantly browm as if the menu is constantly active,
>   even if I hover over a different dropdown on the main navbar.

In your CSS, make sure that the background colour is applied to all states of the `<div>`, not just the hover state. If the `<div>` is nested inside the `<li>`, it will inherit the properties of the `<li>`.

Comment: Thank you Yvonne
the menu was copied from here : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/mega-menu-with-tabs-navigation
and I am customising it to suit my own needs.
Hopefully that might help you and others get a better idea

Comment: hmm, my advice would be to start with a different snippet that is closer to what you want to do, or even better, write the menu from scratch :)

Comment: I wish I could lol I have looked and cannot find anything any closer to what I need.

Id love to write it from scratch but I am very new to web design and do not have anywhere near the knowledge especially in javascript nor the funds to Hire someone lol.

I the position of the tabs isnt essential. more the hover instead of click and the background of the navbar tabs. Even in the link above, the dropdown menu is constantly highlighed as if it is active. Ideally Id like to change that. the rest I can live with :-) lol

Comment: With the div, li part above... 
can I keep the div and li that I have currently? 
If i change the order, ie, move the div outside the li, could that keep things the same and sort the problem? or might it have a negative impact?

Comment: if you move the div outside the li, your HTML will be invalid. You could nest both the h3 and the div inside the li though